# OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: text, openoffice.org, spacing, openoffice-writer

I want to write text on the OenOffice.org Writer with 1.15 line spacing but I don't know how to change line spacing .From Format > Paragraph > Indents & Spacing > Line Spacing I couldn't found 1.15.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to `proportional` with `115%`

This question is probably a better fit for SuperUser, not StackOverflow.